# How to prove autocorrelation function converges in distribution to normal distribution

Tags: martingales, central-limit-theorem, time-series, law-of-large-numbers

I am working on the proof of $n^{1/2}[\hat{\rho}(1),...,\hat{\rho}(h)]'\xrightarrow{d}(z_1,...,z_h)'$, where $\hat{\rho}(h)$ is the sample ACF of $x_t$, $\{x_t|t=...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...\}$ are i.i.d.$(0,\sigma^2)$, and $z_t$ i.i.d.~$N(0,1)$.

I have already shown that $n^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^n x_t^2\xrightarrow{p}\sigma^2$ by WLLN. Now, I and stuck with proving $1/n\sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(x_t-\bar{x})(x_{t+h}-\bar{x})\xrightarrow{p}\sigma^2$. After proving that, I can use Martingale central limit theorem to prove $n^{1/2}\hat{\rho}(h)\xrightarrow{d}z_h$ and then use Wold device to finish the proof.

Now I am stuck with convergence of covariance, though I might have worked out some way to show it. Because $(x_t-\bar{x})(x_{t+h}-\bar{x})$ should be martingale difference sequence, we just need to use Weak Law of Large Number to show $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n(Y_t^2-E(Y_t^2|F_{t-1}))\xrightarrow{p}\sigma^2$, where $Y_t=(X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})$. But I am stuck here for a long while, so can someone please give some help or point some other method?

Appreciate that.

Note, the problem is from Shumway Time Series Analysis and Its Applications With R Examples, 4th Edition, Chapter 1, exercise 1.32, question (d).
[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: $1/n\sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(x_t-\bar{x})(x_{t+h}-\bar{x})\xrightarrow{p}0$ not to $\sigma^2$, since $x_t$ is zero-mean iid with bounded second moments. Further, your $Y_t$ is not an mds.

Comment: @Math-fun Yes I have shown that $Y_t=1/n\sum(x_t-\bar{x})(x_{t+h}-\bar{x})$ not being MDS, so I am thinking about showing $Y_t$ being strictly stationary and just simply use CLT to show (d) problem. But it seems to prove $Y_t$ is strictly stationary, we need to prove $Y_t$ being normally distributed (which is exactly what we want to prove in the end). So how to figure out other ways to show the strictly stationary of $Y_t$?